# Calculating which multiplication a scroll position falls into

Tags: c#, math

I need to monitor the scroll of a FlowLayoutPanel to see if the scroll is dropped in certain ranges, here's and example:

- Scroll Y 1 to 405 = 1
- Scroll Y 406 to 810 = 2
- Scroll Y 811 to 1215 = 3

How might I calculate for a dynamic scroll length which number reference the scroll has fallen under?

An example is if the scroll is at 850 then that's a 3, at 450 then that's a 2. Basically each 405 multiplication increases the number.

Here's where I would need to implement the check.

```
private void ChangedParentFlowPanel_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
   int NewPos = e.NewValue;
   //Check here to see which multiplication of 405 the NewPos falls under 1,2,3,4....

}
```

Comment: `(NewPos - 1) / 405 + 1`?

Comment: Is the 1015 a typo?  Should that really be 1215?

Comment: YOops, yes, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple integer division will do the job:

```
int multiplication = (NewPos - 1) / 405 + 1;
```

I would also recommend you to use named variable instead of magic number 405 to make your code clear for other programmers. And use *camelCase* names for local variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ChangedParentFlowPanel_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
   int NewPos = e.NewValue;
   int ScrollCategory = (NewPos - 1) / 405 + 1;

}
```

I think this would work for what you're trying to do. It's got to be integer division or it won't work, naturally.